# fatal exception at the time of login

Tags: android

I am working with android. Here I created one login form, but when I execute the application and enter login id and password at that time i get fatal exception. when user enter right id and password then he/she will go to next page and if id or password is wrong than one alert box will display.

**HomeActivity :**

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    Button Login;
    EditText UserName, Password;
    private String userid = new String();
    private String pass = new String();
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                userid="tsp";
                pass="tyco";

                if (UserName.getText().toString().equals(userid) &&
                           Password.getText().toString().equals(pass)) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(context,SearchData.class) ;
                    startActivity(in);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
                    dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert.create().show();

                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: initialize context after `setContentView`

Comment: your context must be null as object initialization done before onCreate() of an activity so try to assign context after `setContentView` still you should share your logcat output of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your '**EditText**' UserName and  Password

You should do something like this

```
UserName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
```

Where et_username and et_password should be your ids in your activity_home.xml layout for Username and Password respectively.

Also

change

```
 Intent in = new Intent(context,SearchData.class) ;
                    startActivity(in);
```

To

```
 Intent in = new Intent(Home.this,SearchData.class) ;
                startActivity(in);
```